# Good source of exercises in computing $\operatorname{Tor}$ and $\operatorname{Ext}$ groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, online-resources

I am planning to attend special lectures on geometry and mathematical physics, and the professor advised me in advance to make sure I am familiar with various computations of $\operatorname{Tor}$ and $\operatorname{Ext}$ arising from algebraic topology.

Since I am already familiar to the (graduate level) conceptual/theoretical constructions of homological algebra, I would like to further my understanding by solving many examples.

Any recommendation on a source of exercises containing explicit computation of $\operatorname{Tor}$ and $\operatorname{Ext}$ groups will be appreciated. It would be even better if the problems contain concrete geometric/topological context.

Comment: Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* lists a handful of axioms for both Tor and Ext (in the sections on universal coefficient theorems) from which you can compute them for finitely generated abelian groups. It's great that you already know how these things are constructed, but that's quite often unnecessary when using them in topology.

Comment: One good exercise to do is to compute the Ext groups between shifts of the regular module in the category of graded modules over a polynomial ring. This is good on a mechanical level, to actually be thinking about resolutions etc, and leads into Serre duality for coherent sheaves on projective space, which is worth knowing. Also computing the Ext groups between modules of differentials for projective space is a hands on computation that leads to very interesting conceptual things.

Comment: @ChrisH Thank you very much for the comment. Could you suggest specific materials (e.g. textbook or anything) dealing with them? You can also promote your comment to an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you very much! Could you also suggest interesting problems about Tor & Ext arising in algebraic geometry? Maybe you can make your comment into an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: This might be too advanced, but Ext/Cotor groups over various (co)operation algebras also arise as inputs to spectral sequences that compute "geometric" things.  See e.g. the Adams spectral sequence used to compute homotopy groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some nice exercises for working with Ext groups. They will take place in the ring of graded $R=k[x_1,x_2,..,x_n]$ modules. You can set $n=1$ or $n=2$ if the general case is too imposing too.

1. Compute all the Ext groups $Ext^i(R,R\langle n\rangle)$, where $\langle n \rangle$ denotes shifting the grading by $n$.
2. Compute all the self extensions of the trivial $R$ module $k$ by itself, $Ext^i(k,k)$. For bonus points, compute the algebra structure on this graded ring $S=Ext^*(k,k)$.
3. Once you work out what $S$ is as a graded ring (or extrapolate from the $n=1$ case) compute the extension groups for the trivial graded $S$ module $k$: $$R'=Ext^*_S(k,k).$$ It turns out this ring $R'$ is isomorphic to the polynomial ring $R$ you started with! This phenomenon is known as Koszul duality, and is completely computable in this setup, just set $n=1$ if you don't want to deal with indices.

Now you do say that you want familiarity with Ext and Tor from algebraic topology, so you should definitely compute Ext and Tor groups between all cyclic groups. One more type of concrete computation to do is to compute $Tor^i(M,N)$ for two modules, first by resolving $M$ then tensoring with $N$, then taking homology, or switching the roles of $M$ and $N$. The result you get is the same, even though the resolutions can look very different. Proving this is a nice homological algebra exercise, but is less hands on.